# I want customize file upload but doesn't work

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I want customize `content` about `file upload`:

```
<ng-container >
    <p-fileUpload name="demo[]" customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="customUploader($event)" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" multiple="false" maxFileSize="1000000" 
        (onSelect)="selectaFile($event)" showCancelButton="false" showUploadButton="false">
//I have one single file
            <ng-template pTemplate='content'>
                <div><span>{{file.name}}</span>
                    <button icon="pi pi-times" pbutton type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" (click)="remove($event)"> </button></div>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
```

The problem is that when the component shows me the selected file it shows default behaviour and not mine. This display the element in the default primeng behaviour , but I want display element like I want

I follow this tutorial:

[file upload primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fileupload)

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3iEo.png)

```
<p-fileUpload name="demo[]" customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" multiple="false" maxFileSize="1000000" 
    showCancelButton="false" showUploadButton="false">
            <ng-template pTemplate='content'>
                <div><span *ngIf="file != null">{{file.name}}</span>
                    <button icon="pi pi-times" pbutton type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only">Remove</button></div>
            </ng-template>
    </p-fileUpload>
```

[And here is result. It work normaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou6jx.png)